# How to create shortcut keys in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, extjs3

I write this code for submit on Enter

```
 {
    fieldLabel : 'Password',
    name : 'j_password',
    inputType : 'password',
    allowBlank : false,
    listeners : {
        'render' : function(cmp) {
                 cmp.getEl().on('keypress', function(e) {
                      if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                          submitform();
                      }
                 });
         }
     }
   }
```

What change do I need to do for shortcut keys Like `Save(Ctrl + S)`,`Paste(Ctrl +P)`, Open `(Ctrl + O)`, `Exit(Ctrl +X)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write appropriate handler to do the job using KeyMap.
Ext 4 code snippet may be as follows -

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap(document,{                
            key: [VALUES-ASCII], // this works,
            fn: function(){ alert('key was pressed.!'); }
        }
    );
});
```

[This may Help](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176082-Short-Cut-keys-for-Menu-Bar)

Comment: i am using Extjs 3.4 give me any example about extjs 3.4 Ext.util.KeyMap not available in Extjs 3.4

Comment: `Ext.keyMap` is there for Ext 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think, You will solve your problem by this code

I Give many ways.

You choose suitable one from binding:[{}]

```
                scope     :  this,
                listeners : {                       
                    afterrender: function(window, options) {
                        this.keyNav = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
                            target: window.el,
                            binding: [{
                                key: [10,13],
                                fn: function(){
                                    alert("Return was pressed");
                                }
                            }, {
                                key: "abc",
                                fn: function(){                                    
                                    alert('a, b or c was pressed');
                                }
                            }, {
                                key: "\t",
                                ctrl:true,
                                fn: function(){
                                     submitform();//'Control + tab was pressed
                                }
                            }, {
                                key: "m",
                                ctrl:true,
                                fn: function(){
                                     submitform();//'Control + m was pressed
                                }
                            }],
                            scope: this
                        }); 
                    }
                }
```

Comment: nice! where goes this? how to integrate into a extjs 5 viewController?